# Error cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

I want to move from action in notification to other activity

```
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_stat_share,
           res.getString(R.string.action_share),
startService(new Intent(NewMessageNotification.this,FloatingService.class)))
```

Comment: Is `startService` a static method? Could you share the code for this class?

Comment: @DarshanMehta 
error not in (startService) ,error in (NewMessageNotification.this)

Comment: You cannot refer to an object with `this` out of a `static` context. `static` means that there is no instance of this class (an object), yet `this` refers to the current instance of the class. Calling `this` from a `static` context is a logical error. (You can't call something that you don't have)